# IE8 jquery load() not loading where specified

Tags: jquery

I have the following form:

```
<div id="divSignup">
     <form method="post" name="signupForm" id="signupForm">
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" class="email2"/>
          <input type="hidden" id="SAMID" name="SAMID" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" id="x_building" name="x_building" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" id="x_street" name="x_street" value="" />

          <div id="divSignupForm">
               <cfinclude template="signup1.cfm">
          </div>
     </form>
</div>
```

A template with submit button is dynamically loaded with the `<cfinclude>` tag.
OnSubmit of signup1.cfm, jQuery validates the form then changes the form name and id attributes and loads a new form, again with its own submit button.

```
$('#divSignupForm').load('signup2.cfm',function(){
    $('#signupForm').attr({'name':'signupForm2','id':'signupForm2'});
})
```

This all works great in FF and Chrome and IE9 but not IE8.

In IE8, it seems to load the new form but not within the specified div. It seems to be loading BENEATH the specified div. When I alert the contents of the div with the following:

```
alert($('#divSignupForm').html());
```

I get the following result, which clearly shows the `</FORM>` end tag above the loaded content. **NOTE: Neither of the included templates have `<form>` tags. There is only the single form tag set in the parent.**

Could it be some tag in the loaded form that IE8 doesn't like? Possible jQuery conflict? The site uses MooTools also.

[image]

Comment: does signup2.cfm have the form tag included in it?

Comment: IE is not very graceful with not properly formatted HTML and i've seen it do things like what you mentioned. What does singup2.cfm look like. Could you post that

Comment: I'm assuming some html in the inserted html is causing the resulting html to be invalid html, as such IE8 may be trying to auto-correct the problem. Only cause FF or Chrome render invalid html it doesn't mean it's right. Each browser tries their best to render given html, regardless but I think IE will try to force valid html if it can more so than other browsers. Copy paste the html you get from your call into the place you think it should be in, then copy-paste your complete html into http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input